# RaspBerry pi B rev2 - Issue while sampling a LM335 (temp. sensor) thru a MCP3208 ADC via SPI in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I tried to interface a RaspBerry pi with a LM335 temperature sensor this week-end. I'm using a MCP 3208 micro controller (channel 0) to interface the sensor. My goal is to collect samples data in SPI mode with python 3 scripts (classes).
I've checked the wiring and everything seems OK for me, I'but I'am a beginner, not really aware of Electronic concepts.
On the software side , I've installed quick2wire that claims to be **python 3** compatible. In fact I want to lead the micro-controller with Python 3 API's (not thru shell calls)

### Components

- Raspberry pi REV2 model B with Rasbian-wheezy / Quick2wire installed. */dev/spix.y devices are listed*.
- MCP3208 ADC : 12 bits ADC / SPI. I'm using CS0 from the GPIO. The sensor is connected to channel 0 (**B**). [see datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf).
- LM335 : temperature sensor. Outputs 10mV / °K. Min 5muA / Max 5 mA. It's connected to the MCP3208 channel #0 (**A**). [see datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/nationalsemiconductor/DS005698.PDF)
- 220 ohms resistor (**C**). set up regarding LM335 outputs and desired temperature range coverage with my own calculations : May be a problem ...

### Schematics extract

The LM335 (zener diode like) is connected as :

[image: LM335 / MCP3208 channel wiring]

### Wiring

Components are wired as shown bellow. Note that the yellow link is connected behind the cobbler kit on the CS0 SPI channel.

[image: Using a pi cobbler kit]

### Quick2wire

I use the bellow script to query the CS0/Channel 0 GPIO interface. Unfortunately, I've not found usefull informations on the quick2wire-python-api API's. I've just copy/paste an example found as it was written in the same goal. I'm not sure if it really works :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from quick2wire.spi import *
import sys, time

try:
        channel = int(sys.argv[1])
except:
        channel = 0

MCP3208 = SPIDevice(channel, 0)

while True:
        try:
                response = MCP3208.transaction(writing_bytes(0x41, 0x13), reading(1))
                print ("output = %i" % ord(response[0]))
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
```

The script outputs :

```
output = 0 
output = 0 
output = 0 
output = 0 
output = 0 
 ....
```

The result is the same with the channel 1 ( with argv = 1)

As the MCP3208 Din (probe output) receives  voltage (see bellow) quick2wire should read at 18°C (rawghly my home inside temperature today)

- 3,3 V / 2^12 = 805 muA as I understand as "*digital step*"
- 18°C + 273°C = 291 => 2,91 V on the micro controller **Din** pin
- and then return 2 910 / 0.805 = **3 615**

Am I wrong ?

### Controls

I've no oscilloscope, the only measures I can read are :

- Voltage is 2.529 V at **B** checkpoint and 0,5 V (+/-5%) on the other MCP3208 channels

Note : the adjust pin is not used on the LM335 so results way not be accurate but voltage is here !

Seems to be a problem on the quick2wire side I think. But which ?

### Code

The quick2wire.spi.SPIDevice class lakes of détails on the transfers parameter in terms of structure, content and output response format.

```
def transaction(self, *transfers):
    """
    Perform an SPI I/O transaction.

    Arguments:
    *transfers -- SPI transfer requests created by one of the reading,
                  writing, writing_bytes, duplex or duplex_bytes 
                  functions.

    Returns: a list of byte sequences, one for each read or duplex
             operation performed.
    """
    transfer_count = len(transfers)
    ioctl_arg = (spi_ioc_transfer*transfer_count)()

    # populate array from transfers
    for i, transfer in enumerate(transfers):
        ioctl_arg[i] = transfers[i].to_spi_ioc_transfer()

    ioctl(self.fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(transfer_count), addressof(ioctl_arg))

    return [transfer.to_read_bytes() for t in transfers if t.has_read_buf]
```

*Another question :*

- how to set SPI configuration values like mode, clock speed, bits per word, LSB ... and so on.

**Thanks in advance for your help**.

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, I know it has been quite a while since then, but I currently try to achieve exactly the same. Can you give me some info on how you calculated Rc = 220Ω? And what formula do you use to calculate the temperature?

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably intend to learn how to use the ADC, an so this isn't really an answer to your question (I will use your very rich post for sure - thanks), but I'm aware of temperature sensors that already pack data in GPIO serial line, that are best suited for the raspberry.

You really have to read [this awesome tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing), if you haven't already.

Comment: I had a look to your post. Very good job. As you said I'am interested in ADC control in read / write mode. All the stuff I gathered is located here. Feel free to use anything you could find appropriate.